# xUnit test async event handler

Tags: c#, azure, testing, azureservicebus, xunit

I have a class that uses Azure Service Bus and it basically sends an email by putting a message to a queue. When I write an integration tests I need to make sure I can receive the message that's been sent (no, I'm not testing Service Bus). So, here's the code for that:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task PutEmailIntoTheQueue()
    {
        IlgQueueEmailInfo actual = new IlgQueueEmailInfo("from@address.com", "to@address.com", "subject", "test body", MessageBodyType.Text,
            "email1@domain.com",
            "email2@domain.com");

        ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder sbcb =
            new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(SERVICE_BUS_ENDPOINT_S, QUEUE_NAME_S, SAS_KEY_NAME, EMAIL_TESTS_SAS);
        QueueClient receiveClient = new QueueClient(sbcb, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
        bool hasBeenCalled = false;

        //
        // Check values here
        //
        async Task ReceiveMessageHandler(Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Output.WriteLine("Received Message\n");

            Assert.True(message.Label != null && message.ContentType != null &&
                        message.Label.Equals(IlgEmailQueue.MESSAGE_LABEL_S, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                        message.ContentType.Equals("application/json", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            byte[] body = message.Body;
            string msgJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            Output.WriteLine($"json: {msgJson}\n");

            IlgQueueEmailInfo emailInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IlgQueueEmailInfo>(msgJson);
            Assert.NotNull(emailInfo);
            Output.WriteLine("emailInfo is not NULL");

            Assert.Equal(actual, emailInfo);
            Output.WriteLine($"emailInfo equals to actual: {actual == emailInfo}\n");

            Output.WriteLine("Setting hasBeenCalled to True");
            hasBeenCalled = true;

            await receiveClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
        }

        receiveClient.RegisterMessageHandler(
            ReceiveMessageHandler,
            new MessageHandlerOptions(LogMessageHandlerException) {AutoComplete = true, MaxConcurrentCalls = 1});

        await _emailQueue.QueueForSendAsync(actual.FromAddress, actual.ToAddresses[0], actual.Subj, actual.Body, MessageBodyType.Text, actual.CcAddress,
            actual.BccAddress);

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        Assert.True(hasBeenCalled);
    }
```

But when I run it I get an exception saying something like "There's no currently active test". What is the best way of dealing with this kind of tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing Azure Service Bus in a way that you're sending a message on er the wire and receive it. Looking at the code, you want to verify message is contracted in a certain way. Rather than going through the whole send / receive phase, you could short-circuit it by just testing the `Message` constructed by your code. Alternatively, create a plugin to intercept the message just before it's sent. In case you insist on sending/receiving, your code must not exist until assertion is either executed or there's a timeout. And that's due to the fact that message handler is a synchronous API that will continue execution of the test method *before* the message has a change to be processed by the callback. `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))` is not guaranteed to be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My experience with any cloud is one should really be using it in integration tests. Otherwise you're getting surprises.

yes, 5 sec may not be enough but that's not the problem here.

I was thinking about something similar to jasmine.js (and angular) where it has `done()`.

Comment: 1. You're testing metadata. ASB will not change it while sending your message. 2. You're testing the body by simply reading it back. Again, ASB won't change it. So what's the value of sending over the wire?  Anyhow, you can test sending/receiving. Instead of using queue client and register a callback, you could switch to `MesaageReceiver.ReceiveAsync()` to simplify your test method.

Comment: ok, probably you're right and what I'm doing is an overkill. ...but I still have doubts :)

Comment: If your code sends the message and you use `MessageReceiver` to retrieve it, what's to doubt? Perhaps I'm missing something, but you're exercising ASB and message retrieved.